# Роутер с VPN

Tags: vpn, маршрутизация

Доброго времени суток.

Есть задача: Сервер ( RHEL ) и несколько счетчиков (~4000). Счетчики находятся далеко и встала задача поставить туда роутеры и поднять VPN-тунель от сервера к счетчикам чтоб их опрашивать по таймеру.

Вопрос: какие возможные реализации? и какие роутеры или прошивки к ним умеют VPN поверх интернет соединения?

Answer (score 3):

Routerboard + Mikrotik же.Сможешь поднять VPN-over-Ethernet-over-PPP-over-<чего пожелаешь>.

PS: а почему тунель **К** счетчикам а не наоборот?

Comment: VPN сервером естественно является мой сервер, а роутеры - клиентами. Сделал все на DD-WRT. Вполне себе работает :)

Answer (score 2):

Мое мнение - счетчики должны уметь коннектиться по шифрованному протоколу к серверу (TLS) по публичному IP (проброс портов, NAT?) и сливать туда информацию. VPN в данном случае overkill и лишний способ заработать себе неприятности на ровном месте.

Поэтому ответ - используйте правильный софт для мониторинга.